# Commit of offsets threw an unexpected exception for sequence number X

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I'm encountering an error with Kafka Connect while attempting to commit offsets for a sink task. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
`2024-02-12 01:11:26,142 ERROR || WorkerSinkTask{id=prd-procurement.public.allocation2-0} Commit of offsets threw an unexpected exception for sequence number 2506: {topic.public.table-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=437542, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}`
```

This error seems to indicate that the offset commit failed unexpectedly for a specific sequence number. I'm using Kafka Connect to sink data into an external system, and reliable offset committing is crucial for data consistency and fault tolerance.

I'm seeking guidance on how to diagnose and resolve this issue effectively. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding:

Potential causes of this offset commit error.
Steps to troubleshoot and identify the root cause.
Best practices for configuring Kafka Connect and sink connectors to ensure reliable offset commits.
Any known limitations or common pitfalls related to offset committing in Kafka Connect.
Additionally, I'd appreciate any insights or experiences from the community that can help me address this issue and ensure the stability and reliability of my Kafka Connect setup.

I've carefully examined the Kafka Connect logs to gather more information about the error. However, the error message provided doesn't offer much insight into the root cause.

Comment: is this error intermittent or you never could commit an offset back to Kafka cluster?

Comment: I encounter similar problem, and it keeps happening. still not sure the root cause. In my case I use aiven GCS sink connector. Oddly when I tried to use another topic, I haven't found any error regarding offset commits, so I am not sure whether the problem is from kafka connect or topic. have you found anything @Vinura Jayalath

Comment: `INFO [de-lsm-gcs-connector|task-1] [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-de-lsm-gcs-connector-1, groupId=connect-de-lsm-gcs-connector] Fetch position FetchPosition{offset=21801, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[kafka01-kafka-0.kafka01-kafka-brokers.kafka-operator.svc:9092 (id: 0 rack: asia-southeast2-a)], epoch=140}} is out of range for partition loan_logs-4, resetting offset (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher) [task-thread-de-lsm-gcs-connector-1]`btw did you also find something like this along with the error you mention above ?